# "Another form of ___ is/are" Which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

I looked for this on here but I couldn't find it.

I have the sentence, "Another form of patterns **is** tessellations."

My question is, in this case is the correct word "is" or "are"?

Comment: Subject: form (singular) so "is" is correct

Comment: But consider *pattern* and *tessellation.* Do you really need plurals for those? That's why *is* sounds odd, however correct it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Form of patterns" is a noun phrase, with the headword being "form". Therefore, the correct word is "is", because "form" is a singular noun...